# PHP live site is different from Local ( Bootstrap )

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bit of a problem my LIVE site looks a lot of different then my Local site in PHP storm, and I have used all -webkit- and -moz- where it was needed but somehow and sometimes it ignores Bootstrap =\

tried to upload the whole testing project to my webhosting ( www.nekonomagic.sk ) but it looks weird =\

whole site uses a request command on templates

> LIVE : nekonomagic.sk

[image]

> Expected :

[image]

Comment: Open the developer tools (F12 in Chrome) and inspect the elements which are different to check if there's any styles not being applied. Also if you're using raw CSS in your local and aggregating/minifying on live then the order of CSS rules may have changed and you're getting things overwritten.

Comment: When I check the site through Chrome, it looks like the lower image. Are you using the exact same browser when checking local and live? If not, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yea same browser GOOGLE CHROME

plus i use on LOCAL and LIVE same minifying files

Comment: tested true https://www.browserling.com and it worked on Safari mozila and chrome so looks like it only no works for me ? is it passible ?, Cache and Cookies clieared and checked by incognito